# How to Overcome Bootstrap's Default Styling? Element targeting issues?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've been rebuilding my website in Bootstrap in order to get a quick prototype up while I design something a bit more robust myself. It's been proving more bother than it's worth when it comes to overriding the default styling.

The website is [here](http://kennethfrancis.com) if you need it for reference.

I'm trying to get the background colour of the "Home" link to be white. I've succeeded in styling the other `navbar` links.

Here's an example of the type of CSS I was using to target (I don't think there are issues here):

```
.white-back, #home {
    background-color: white;
}
```

HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active" id="home"><a href="http://kennethfrancis.com">Home</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

I've tried putting an ID on `li.active` as well as on the contained `a`. It didn't work when I set the background colour of `li.active > a` to white. I tried even using `!important`. Is there something I'm missing here? I attacked a couple of different ways based on what the Firebug inspector said that object was.

Now, looking at this with everything else stripped out around it makes me feel as though I've gone nested-div crazy. Can I strip any of these away and maintain the structure of the page?

It would be great also if anyone could toss in any links about how to overcome this sort of element targeting/overriding problem. Anything relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using class then you need to make sure your CSS is more specific to be applied. So `li.active a` won't work as it gets overridden by default Bootstrap classes since it's more specific than your styles.

You need to target like the below code for it to work

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a {
  background: #fff;
}
```

In case you are using id `#home` for `li`, then you can use

```
#home a {
  background: #fff;
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I've downloaded your page ... in your style.css, just place this class:

```
.navbar-default.navbar-fixed-top .nav > li.active > a {
    background: white !important; 
}
```